# ActiveAdmin error uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin::Dashboards

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin, dashboard

ActiveAdmin dashboard is no longer working after upgrading to 0.6.1. The dashboard now returns the error:

```
  /app/app/admin/dashboards.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin::Dashboards (NameError)
```

---

**Update SOLVED:**

The dashboard has been removed from ActiveAdmin 0.6.1. To continue using the dashboard, force version 0.6.0 in your application's Gemfile:

```
 gem "activeadmin", "0.6.0"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveAdmin::Dashboards has been removed on 0.6.1.
Make sure bundler is not installing that version.